# Setting a default value for a field that is bound to a table

Tags: sql, visual-studio, default

I have  a field Main Language in a client contacts table in SQL. I want to set the default value to English but allow it to be changed at run time. At runtime the field has a drop down list based on a table Languages whose format is name, code and id. The record in the languages table with English as the name is English, 2201, 266. The field stored in the contacts table is the id (266).
I have tried setting the default value to 'English' and 266 but it just shows English or 266 at run time and prevents the drop down list from working. Even when I set it to 266 and I can see 266 in field in Object explorer, it does not show English at run time - it shows 266.

Comment: Hi WendyC. Try to give us more information about your case. Maybe preparing a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.